# windows 10 reset without uninstall desktop apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

[image]

My windows store app and other store apps broken.

I'm already trying `Add-AppxPackage` command. But following error occurred.

[image]

I'm also trying `WSReset.exe`. But this windows appear.

[image]

**How to fix store app without uninstalling desktop programs**?

Comment: **You can't.**  You cannot perform a "Reset" and keep your install desktop programs installed.

Comment: no, this is how that feature works: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 possible options:

Option 1

Open system restore (Control panel -> Recovery -> Open system restore) and restore to an earlier time and date

Option 2

```
Navigate to "C:/Program files/WindowsApps" search for a file called windows store delete the folder
```

Then try these steps:
[windowstorereisntall](http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/8284-how-reinstall-store.html)

Option 3

```
Firstly try refreshing the PC by:

Windows -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Reset this PC -> Keep files

If it asks for recovery or installation Cd you will need to make a bootable USB using https://rufus.akeo.ie/

You can download windows 10 ISO from Microsoft website
```

I strongly prefer windows 8/8.1 method which is really straight forward and reliable

Comment: The Windows 10 method is identical to the Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 method.  Only difference is there is a signal option that does both Reset and Refresh with Windows 10